# How can I set Task timeout in JavaFx?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task

I have a class with one method that get data through usb device and add it into ArrayList:

```
public class usbDevice {
    public Task<Void> readData() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                //read data through usb device and add it into array;
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I call this method when press the button inside controller class which extends USB_device class:

```
@FXML
void readUSB(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../resources/loadingPage.fxml"));
        Scene scene = startButton.getScene();

        root.translateXProperty().set(scene.getWidth());
        parent.getChildren().add(root);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(root.translateXProperty(), 0 , Interpolator.EASE_IN);
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), keyValue);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);

        timeline.setOnFinished(event1 -> {
            parent.getChildren().remove(container);
            Task<Void> readTask = readData();
            Thread t = new Thread(readTask);
            t.start();
        });
        timeline.play();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But sometimes I get stuck in this method and I need to reconnect to my usb device if after 10 seconds, for example, I did not get the data. How can I set timeout which will reconnect my usb device every 10 seconds in this thread until I get data through it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html):

```
public class USBDevice {
    public Task<Void> readData() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {

                CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                    //read data through usb device and add it into array;
                });
                try {
                    future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    // get here if read was successful
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
                    // exception was thrown by code reading usb device
                } catch (TimeoutException te) {
                    // timeout occurred
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```